# Simulate a virtual copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, this, copy-constructor

I am a newbie to c++ and just learning by reading a book.
So the question may be a bit stupid.
Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fish
{
public:
    virtual Fish* Clone() = 0;

};

class Tuna : public Fish
{
public:
        Tuna(const Tuna& SourceTuna)
    {
        cout << "Copy Constructor of Tuna invoked" << endl;
    }


    Tuna* Clone()
    {
        return new Tuna(*this);
    }
};
```

I have question on

```
return new Tuna(*this);
```

First, why does the copy constructor return a pointer of Tuna?
Usually, invoking the copy constructor will return a copied instance directly.
For example:

```
class Student
{   
public:
    Student(){}
    Student(const Student& Input) { cout << "Copy Ctor Invoked\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Student a;
    Student b(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Base on my understanding, what `Student b(a);` does is copying an instance of a and named `b`.
So why does `new Tuna(*this)` is not returning an instance instead of a pointer?

Second, why is point of this,ie. `*this` , provided in the argument?
Base on my understanding `this` is a pointer to the current object, which mean `*this` is a pointer to the pointer of the current object. I try to use `int` to simulate the situation.

```
// The input argument is the same as a copy constructor
int SimulateCopyConstructor(const int& Input){ return 0; }

void main()
{
    int a = 10;     // a simulate an object
    int* b = &a;    // b is a pointer of object a, which simulate "this"
    int** c = &b;   // c is a pointer to pointer of object a, which simulate of "*this"

    SimulateCopyConstructor(a); // It can compile
    SimulateCopyConstructor(b); // cannot compile
    SimulateCopyConstructor(c); // cannot compile
}
```

I think sending `(*this)` to copy constructor is similar to the situation c above. But it does not compile. So how does it works?

Comment: `*this` is dereferencing the `this` pointer to get the object, it does not create a pointer to pointer. `clone` is not a copy constructor, it is a regular member function. It returns by pointer because of slicing issues when returning a base class to a polymorphic object. `clone` is also poorly designed, it should at least return a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Search the web for "c++ factory design" and "c++ double delegation" for more examples.

Comment: @nwp Thanks. `*this` is dereferencing the `this` pointer to get the object.
This figure out what I ignored.
Using the above example.
`SimulateCopyConstructor(*b);` simulate the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Student b(a);
```

Does not return a `Student` object. It declares it and instructs compiler to call a copy contructor on the new object allocated on stack.

```
new Student(a);
```

This indeed returns a pointer to a new `Student` object because `operator new` does. And `(a)` there instructs the compiler to call a copy contructor on that object that was allocated by `new`.

However if you had a function doing this:

```
Student foo(){ return Student(a); }
```

That would create a new `Student` object on stack, call copy constructor and then return the resulting object from the function.

Comment: Thanks. You make me understand my first problem
Just be reminded `new something;` return the pointer of `something`
Just like `new int` returns `int*`